# Colors washed out in cam preview but vibrant in Google Photo, Gimp, Lightroom mobile

Tags: android, gimp, color-space, color-profile, srgb

My phone (OPPO Reno2) takes photos in "Display P3" color profile (that is, if I open the image in gimp, it asks me if I want to convert it to srgb).

- When I edit the image with google photo, the colors remain looking good.
- When I open the image with other android apps (like snapseed, or "Polish photo editor"), save it, then the colors look washed out (using the same device and google photo for displaying)
- However! When I open the original image in gimp, convert it to srgb, then the colors look good.

It looks like android apps (with exception of google photo editor), either ignore the image color profile, or do a poor job in converting to srgb.

Example: This is a screenshot in google photos. On the right, the original photo. On the left, the same photo, after loaded into Polish Photo Editor and saved, without any editing. The colors on the left photo are a bit "washed out". I would expect colors on both images to be exactly the same, but they are not.
[image]

This affects also the default system gallery, and even the CAMERA app preview.
[image]
Meaning the colors in Google Photo, Lightroom mobile, Gimp, are more vibrant than the preview in the cam app when taking the photo.

So, if I want to edit a photo without the "washed out" color effect, I have to:

- Either use google photo edit, which usually does not have the features I need;
- or first download it to my laptop, then using gimp convert the color profile to srgb, then upload it to my phone, and then I can edit it.

Questions:

1. Is there an android app which can convert a photo from Display P3 color profile to srgb, just like gimp does?
2. Are there other photo editor apps (apart from google photo editor) which handle the Display P3 color profile correctly?

Thank you!

Current workaround is download photo to PC, use gimp to convert color profile to srgb, then upload it back to the cloud/phone. I want a phone-only solution.

Edit:
I think I understand what is going on. All those apps (snapseed, Polish Photo Editor, system gallery and camera app) are not "wide color gamut ready", as described in the [Android Developers Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/05/wide-color-photos-are-coming-to-android.html)

> A wide color gamut ready application implies the application manages
> color proactively. This means when given images, the application
> always checks the color space and does conversion based on its
> capability of showing wide color gamut, and thus even if the
> application can't handle wide color gamut it can still show the sRGB
> color gamut of the image correctly without color distortion.

> However, if your application is not color correct, then typically your
> application will end up manipulating/displaying the image without
> converting the color space correctly, resulting in color distortion.
> For example you may get the below image, where the color is washed-out
> and everything looks distorted.